Power BI Web - Dynamic Data Source Refresh Workaround (Udemy Business API)
I'm creating a Power BI report that pulls data from several web API's. This source is Udemy's Business API. It includes a dynamic refresh, and I keep running into this error because it seems that the web service isn't equipped to handle dynamic refreshes properly:

This dataset includes a dynamic data source. Since dynamic data sources aren't refreshed in the Power BI service, this dataset won't be refreshed

I've come across a workarounds on Stack Overflow (example) and other sites (example 2). They seem to reference using Web.Contents() in a certian way, but I'm struggling to figure out how to implement that into this script and not very familiar with the power query language yet.
I would appreciate any help or guidance that anybody could provide on adjusting this code to work on the web service. (I've excluded a few of the last rows because they are just data transformations within power query, not relevant for this).
let     
    BaseUrl = "https://[Organization].udemy.com/api-2.0/organizations/[OrgKey]/analytics/user-course-activity/",
    EntitiesPerPage = 100,
 
    GetJson = (Url) =>
        let Options = [Headers=[ #"Authorization" = "[authorization code]"]],
            RawData = Web.Contents(Url, Options),
            Json    = Json.Document(RawData)
        in  Json,
 
    GetEntityCount = () =>
        let Url   = BaseUrl,
            Json  = GetJson(Url),
            Count = Json[#"count"]
        in  Count,
 
    GetPage = (Index) =>
        let Page = "?&page=" & Text.From(Index),
            Page_Size = "&page_size=100",
            Url   = BaseUrl & Page & Page_Size,
            Json  = GetJson(Url),
            Value = Json[#"results"]
        in  Value,
 
    EntityCount = List.Max({ EntitiesPerPage, GetEntityCount() }),
    PageCount   = Number.RoundUp(EntityCount / EntitiesPerPage),
    PageIndices = {1 .. PageCount},
    Pages       = List.Transform(PageIndices, each GetPage(_)),
    Entities    = List.Union(Pages),
    Table       = Table.FromList(Entities, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Table, "Column1", {"user_name", "user_surname", "user_email", "user_role", "user_external_id", "course_id", "course_title", "course_category", "course_duration", "completion_ratio", "num_video_consumed_minutes", "course_enroll_date", "course_start_date", "course_completion_date", "course_first_completion_date", "course_last_accessed_date", "is_assigned", "assigned_by", "user_is_deactivated", "lms_user_id"}, {"Column1.user_name", "Column1.user_surname", "Column1.user_email", "Column1.user_role", "Column1.user_external_id", "Column1.course_id", "Column1.course_title", "Column1.course_category", "Column1.course_duration", "Column1.completion_ratio", "Column1.num_video_consumed_minutes", "Column1.course_enroll_date", "Column1.course_start_date", "Column1.course_completion_date", "Column1.course_first_completion_date", "Column1.course_last_accessed_date", "Column1.is_assigned", "Column1.assigned_by", "Column1.user_is_deactivated", "Column1.lms_user_id"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Column1", each [Column1.course_enroll_date] <> null and [Column1.course_enroll_date] <> ""),
    

"What I've tried" portion:
I wasn't even certain where to begin to be honest. I've tried inserting the web.content() function into a few different places, but I don't understand how it's supposed to work and I wasn't able to create a working query.
Here is my latest attempt:
let     
    BaseUrl = Web.Contents("https://[Organization].udemy.com/api-2.0/organizations/[OrgKey]/analytics/user-course-activity/"),
    EntitiesPerPage = 100,
 
    GetJson = (Url) =>
        let Options = [Headers=[ #"Authorization" = "[AUTHORIZATION]"]],
            RawData = Web.Contents(Url, Options),
            Json    = Json.Document(RawData)
        in  Json,
 
    GetEntityCount = () =>
        let Url   = Web.Contents(BaseUrl),
            Json  = GetJson(Url),
            Count = Json[#"count"]
        in  Count,
 
    GetPage = (Index) =>
        let Page = "?&page=" & Text.From(Index),
            Page_Size = "&page_size=100",
            Url   = Web.Contents(BaseUrl & Page & Page_Size),
            Json  = GetJson(Url),
            Value = Json[#"results"]
        in  Value,
 
    EntityCount = List.Max({ EntitiesPerPage, GetEntityCount() }),
    PageCount   = Number.RoundUp(EntityCount / EntitiesPerPage),
    PageIndices = {1 .. PageCount},
    Pages       = List.Transform(PageIndices, each GetPage(_)),
    Entities    = List.Union(Pages),
    Table       = Table.FromList(Entities, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Table, "Column1", {"user_name", "user_surname", "user_email", "user_role", "user_external_id", "course_id", "course_title", "course_category", "course_duration", "completion_ratio", "num_video_consumed_minutes", "course_enroll_date", "course_start_date", "course_completion_date", "course_first_completion_date", "course_last_accessed_date", "is_assigned", "assigned_by", "user_is_deactivated", "lms_user_id"}, {"Column1.user_name", "Column1.user_surname", "Column1.user_email", "Column1.user_role", "Column1.user_external_id", "Column1.course_id", "Column1.course_title", "Column1.course_category", "Column1.course_duration", "Column1.completion_ratio", "Column1.num_video_consumed_minutes", "Column1.course_enroll_date", "Column1.course_start_date", "Column1.course_completion_date", "Column1.course_first_completion_date", "Column1.course_last_accessed_date", "Column1.is_assigned", "Column1.assigned_by", "Column1.user_is_deactivated", "Column1.lms_user_id"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Column1", each [Column1.course_enroll_date] <> null and [Column1.course_enroll_date] <> ""),
   

